# Как передать куки от одного поддомена к другому?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть селект со списком городов, кликаю на один из городов записываю название города в куку на js (тут же в консоле её вывожу, и она выводится). 
Через несколько секунд происходит переадресация на поддомен с городом на который кликнул, например, `msk.site.ru`. 
Как на этом поддомене `msk.site.ru` получить мою куку?

```js
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  if(!expires) expires = new Date(2100,01,01);
  if(!path) path = '/';
  //var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
  var curCookie = name + "=" + value +
    "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() +
    "; path=" + path +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
  document.cookie = curCookie;
  console.log(curCookie);
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option>Москва</option>
   <option>Санкт-Петербург</option>
   <option>Воронеж</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Покажите, как ставите куки. Надо дать им доп. параметр domain: `Set-Cookie: city=msk.site.ru; domain=site.ru`

Comment: @Sergiks добавил в тему,и как добавить множество поддоменов т.к у меня получается будет и spb.site.ru и voronezh.site.ru и тд

Comment: Просто `.site.ru` и кука будет доступна на всех поддоменах

Comment: а на основном сайте она также будет работать?верно?

Comment: @test_q_1 верно

Comment: пишет undefined,что делать?